# How to change the command history buffer size in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, windows-terminal

I can change the history buffer size of CMD.exe using the preferences:

[image: CMD properties]

But how can I do it when running a CMD shell inside Windows Terminal?  Those settings are nowhere to be found.

**Edit**:

This question has nothing to do with the WT "History size" setting which is documented as:

> **History size**
> This sets the number of lines above the ones displayed in the window you can scroll back to.

This is the equivalent of the CMD "screen buffer size":

[image: Layout properties]

I am asking about the buffer of entered *commands* that you can cycle through using the up and down arrows, or using F7 like this:

[image]

(If you try it in a CMD window running inside WT, it won't display more than 50)

Comment: Try Settings, Profile, Defaults, Advanced and then History Size.

Comment: That setting controls the number of lines in the screen buffer, not the number of remembered commands.

Answer (score 1):

First, some terminology to get us on the same page:

> This is the equivalent of the CMD "screen buffer size"

While most people think of this dialog as part of CMD, it's actually the "Windows Console Host" (`conhost.exe` or "ConHost"), the legacy (20+ years) terminal application for Windows that Windows Terminal is designed to replace.

You can also see the "Command History" option that you reference in any other terminal-based application that you run in Windows Console Host, such as PowerShell or WSL.  Only when hosting a CMD shell, however, does that setting actually control the command history length.

And that was, [to quote one of the Windows Terminal developers](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6500#issuecomment-670065247) (who also is responsible for maintaining ConHost):

> an architectural mistake the likes of which we are not intending to make again.

That's the bad news.  The good news is that you should be able to replicate this functionality with other features.  As one of the other Microsoft team members said in that same Github thread:

> It's not the Terminal's responsibility to remember the commands executed by a commandline client. That's the responsibility of the *shell*.

And, as a shell, CMD itself actually does have this functionality through `doskey.exe`.  E.g.:

```
doskey /listsize=999
```

That will set the command history size to 999, overriding whatever is set in ConHost, as well as the default size of 50 that you are seeing in Windows Terminal.

You can change this for all CMD sessions in Windows Terminal by:

1. Creating a file `winterm_start.cmd` (or whatever you want to call it) in your Profile directory `C:\Users\<username>` (or wherever you want to place it) with:

   ```
   @echo off
   doskey /listsize=999
   ```
2. Opening the Windows Terminal *Settings*
3. Selecting the "Command Prompt" profile.
4. Under the *General* tab (the first one), change the *Command Line*.

   From:

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe
   ```

   To:

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /k %UserProfile%\winterm_start.cmd
   ```

   <sub>(Adjusting, of course, if you changed the filename/location)</sub>

Any new Command Prompt profile you open should now have an expanded command history (including <kbd>F7</kbd> support).

I tested this by pasting 100 lines of:

```
echo 1
echo 2
...
```

... into a Command Prompt in Windows Terminal *without* this change, and it only remembered the most recent 50 commands.  With this change, it remembered all of them (and more, of course).

Comment: This (unfortunately named) setting controls the size of the screen buffer, not the number of remembered commands.

Comment: @AlexO Absolutely right.  And the fact that the Screen Buffer Size settings on the "Layout" tab look very similar to the "Command History" ones makes it even more confusing.  Thanks for clarifying (and updating the question).  Hopefully this answer edit is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the update!  Unfortunately `doskey /listsize` does absolutely nothing on my machine.  In a plain CMD window, the command history size stays the same as specified in the HistoryBufferSize registry setting regardless of the parameter, and in WT it ignores the setting and is fixed to 50

Comment: @AlexO Well bummer. And then, funny story, I started Googling around to see if I could spot why it isn't working for you, and I came across a recent post from someone who also said it wasn't working.  Oops, that turned out to be [you as well](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/2558#issuecomment-1167679362).  Looks like it predates my answer even, so you were already on the same track at least.

Comment: @AlexO I'm curious if it's not working for you because of the buffer limit.  In legacy CMD/ConHost, you bump it to 10.  If it's lower, are there history issues?  If so, then you might be running into the fact that `doskey` is still limited to just the 4 buffers.  I'm wondering if you can run the PowerShell script in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/2558#issuecomment-824215241) in Windows Terminal and then execute`cmd.exe` directly from that shell session.  That *might* make a difference (if the issue is really the number of buffers available).

Comment: No, it just doesn't update the actual number of lines.  Here's an example of trying to set it lower (to 3): https://i.imgur.com/lfl5Ztj.png

Comment: Posted as a separate question: https://superuser.com/questions/1729309/doskey-fails-to-set-listsize-in-cmd

Comment: @AlexO Well I was actually referring to the *"Number of Buffers"* setting, rather than the *"Buffer Size"*, but I didn't state that explicitly.  But in my testing, I haven't been able to see any impact of that *"Number of Buffers"* setting itself, so I posted [this new question](https://superuser.com/q/1729317/1210833) as well.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the number of buffers should not have any impact when there is no contention

Comment: @AlexO Right - That's what I was was wondering - If there was any possibility that contention was coming into play.  You have it set to 10 in ConHost/CMD, I assume because at some point you *did* have a contention issue?

Comment: No, I did it preemptively based on recommendations.  Figured it wouldn't hurt.