# doskey fails to set listsize in CMD

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

`DOSKEY /LISTSIZE=xxx` should change the command history buffer in CMD, but unfortunately it seems to have no effect on my machine.  No matter what value I set, the buffer size is not updated.

I know that I can set it using the properties (or setting the appropriate registry entry), but neither of those works when CMD is running inside Windows Terminal, and the recommendation is to use `DOSKEY` (which, as stated, does not work for me).

Here's an example of trying to lower the size:

[image]

Windows version is: 10.0.19043.1766 (21H1)

Comment: As the OP knows from [another answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1728701/1210833), this is working for me, and according to [a Microsoft Terminal/Console developer](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/2558#issuecomment-678559094) should work.  But we can't figure out why it's not working for @AlexO.